# How to set tab in the bottom of the display in android?

Tags: android

I want to set one tab in the center bottom of the display.

Comment: Why donot you use button instead of Tab?

Comment: A screenshot or diagram of what you are seeking would help people understand your question better. On Android, tabs are usually in a group at the top, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
   <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom = "@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:paddingLeft ="50dip"
        />
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use layout_weight="0" for the TabWidget and layout_weight="1" for the content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:padding="0dp"/>
    <TabWidget 
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```